# Two filters for one selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to do something like this in CSS  (3 included) ?

```
ul li:visible:nth-child(odd) {...}
```

Comment: It is possible, but `:visible` is not a CSS3 property, it is jQuery

Comment: `:visible` is not in any CSS specification.

Comment: is there a way to select only visible elements in CSS only?

Comment: Thank you. Can you write a quick answer so I can mark this solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible purely with CSS. You CAN chain pseudo classes such as [`li:nth-child(2n):hover`](http://jsfiddle.net/pGW9g/1/) but [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) is jQuery, not CSS.

CSS has no similar functionality as CSS cannot currently determine if an element is visible or not

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andy
But it will not select 1st element so add `+1` and the code will `li:nth-child(2n+1):hover.` For other things refer Andy's answer